# Which event triggers when paging DevExpress MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, gridview, devexpress

I got the following scenario:
I've got a gridview where I use the pre-render to set something.
Now after the pre-render I want to change that again.

When the page loads, the life cycle of the control begins. pre-render event triggers in which i set it. And then with the clientside event Init I change the class of that row again.

Now I want to have that same functionality when the user pages through the records of the gridview. But Init wont trigger ofcourse, since the gridview has already been initialized. But I just can't find a clientside event that will trigger like the Init event when the user pages through the records.

The EndCallBack event triggers BEFORE pre-render so that is not an option...
Any idea's which event I could use?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress Support directly?

Comment: they said it isn't possible...